# Let $X,Y\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ and $\Phi_{t}^{X}$ an integral curve of $X$. Show that $\frac{d}{dt}Y(m)(f\circ \Phi_{t}^{X}) =Y(m)(Xf).$

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, lie-derivative

Let $M$ be a manifold, $X,Y\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$. Let $\Phi_{t}^{X}$    an integral curve or flow line  of $X$.  We define 
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
Xf:M &\rightarrow & \mathbb{R} \\
m &\rightarrow & X(m)(f)
\end{array}$$

for all $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$. Show that 
$$\frac{d}{dt}Y(m)(f\circ \Phi_{t}^{X}) =Y(m)(Xf)$$
for any $m \in M$.

**Remark:** I tried but I'm very confused.

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{d}{dt}_{\vert t=0}Y(m)(f\circ \Phi_{t}^{X}) =Y(m)(Xf)$ ?

Comment: You must see $Y(m)$ and $X(m)$ as derivations.

Comment: Ok, so did you try to write down each vector field locally around $m$: $Y=\sum_{k=1}^nY_k\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_k}$ and $X=\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_k}$ ? The equality follows easily applying the chain rule correctly.

Comment: According to your suggestion, the problem is reduced to calculate $\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\left.\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\right|_{m}(f\circ  \Phi_{t}^{X} )\right)$ where $(U,\varphi)=(U;x_1 , \ldots,x_n)$ is a coordinate neigborhood about a point $m$. In this sense,that is  $\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\left.\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r_k}\right|_{\varphi (m)}(f\circ  \Phi_{t}^{X} \circ \varphi^{-1})\right)$ where $r_1 , \ldots,r_n$ be the standar coordinaes on $\mathbb{R}$. I do not know how to follow, I do not see how to apply the chain rule in this case.

Comment: Since the flot is smooth according to any of its variables (time and space) one can use Schwarz theorem stating that $\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\left.\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\right|_{m}(f\circ  \Phi_{t}^{X} )\right)=\left.\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\right|_{m}\left(\dfrac{d}{dt}(f\circ  \Phi_{t}^{X} )\right)$